# #oauth2 security expressions on method level

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

What should I do to be able to use #oauth2 security expressions on method level like on the example below?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "email", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
  public String email() {

    return "test@email.com";
  }
```

If I do a request to that resource I receive

```
    [INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.hasScope('read')'
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:14)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:44)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:57)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:25)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aspectj.AspectJMethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(AspectJMethodSecurityInterceptor.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aspectj.aspect.AnnotationSecurityAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_security_access_intercept_aspectj_aspect_AnnotationSecurityAspect$1$c4d57a2b(AnnotationSecurityAspect.aj:63)
[INFO]  at pl.insert.controllers.ResourceController.email(ResourceController.java:22)
```

The same thing works well if I specify the access in my ResourceServerConfiguration instead of @Controllers' methods

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/resources/**");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
  }
}
```

Standard security expressions like @PreAuthorize("permitAll") or @PreAuthorize("denyAll") work as expected. So, probably I have to tell somehow to my AspectJMethodSecurityInterceptor to use OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Marek ! 
Did you find a solution to your problem ? Same issue here ...

Comment: Unfortunately no, as far as I remember I spent some time with this but the solution was too complicated and finally not worth to implement. I use @Configuration to manually do that :( In my case this is not so painful, but I can imagine that there are cases where it could be.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer

Comment: I juste filed an issue here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3910

Comment: @SébastienNussbaumer check the answer below. I have just found the solution by working on a different problem. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To enable `#oAuth2` security expressions it is only needed to set the default expression handler as `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` instead of `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler`. Because `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` extends it anyway, then the whole previous functionality remains the same. In my configuration I use both `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  ...
}


@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityConfiguration.class, MethodSecurityConfiguration.class })
public class AppConfiguration {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried this, but it didn't help. Could someone please share some source code?

Comment: What does it mean 'it didn't help'? Have the @Configuration class been loaded and createExpressionHandler() method ever been called? If 'yes' check in a debugger if your AspectJMethodSecurityInterceptor really uses OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler. If 'no' investigate why.

Comment: Adding the override to `createExpressionHandler` works fine for me. The other solutions that claim that you can just add the `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` dependency do not work for me (At least no in my unit test, did not check my application itself).

Answer (score 5):

I think you also need to add:
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(**prePostEnabled = true**) in order to get it to work.

[Answered on deferent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638850/how-to-protect-spring-security-oauth-resources-using-preauthorize-based-on-scop)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution would be to let Spring Boot autoconfigure. Adding the following dependency solved this for me:

```
compile('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.4.RELEASE')
```

Comment: I had to delete the configuration related to GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration class and I added this dependency then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, things have changed. With Spring Security 5 one should use:

```
.hasAuthority("SCOPE_scopename")
```

**Spring adds authorities to the principal based on the scopes it received from the provider, prefixed with “SCOPE_“.**

More info: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but only in a unit test (`@WebMvcTest`). I had to add `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` on the inner class that defined the configuration for the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

  @TestConfiguration
  @Import({JacksonCustomizations.class,SecuritySettings.class,
        OAuth2ServerConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfiguration.class,
        TokenGrantersConfiguration.class})
  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
  public static class TestConfig {
  }
}
```

UPDATE: In Spring Boot 2.x, you might get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually activated

The reason is that you added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` without actually enabling anything. To fix it, set at least one of the properties of the annotation to true. E.g:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the combination of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49448368/539048)

```
// spring configuration class annotation
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52832621/539048)

```
// gradle dependencuy
compile('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.4.RELEASE')
```