# @EnableWebSecurity and #oauth2.clientHasRole - Why doesn't it work?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I've been racking my brain against this for some time. I have a `client_credentials` JWT token from Azure with the following in the payload:

```
"roles": [ "read", "write" ]
```

I have a security configuration that looks similar to this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api", "/api/**").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole(\"read\")")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api", "/api/**").access("#oauth2.clientHasRole(\"write\")")
            .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.isClient()");
    }
}
```

I am using:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:2.1.0.RELEASE
```

We were using a private library which used `@EnableResourceServer`, but have since stopped using it as it required internal support by creating custom code to connect to Azure - instead of using `@EnableWebSecurity` which seems to works out of the box except for these special permissions.

So why won't the `#oauth2` security expression methods work? I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#oauth2.clientHasRole("read")'
```

I've tried `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` and manually return an `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler()` by overriding `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.createExpressionHandler()`, but that did not work. See this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612004/3948882) as reference.

As an alternate approach, I've also tried to look into adding some new `GrantedAuthority`s but had no luck figuring out how to do that without manually authenticating a token myself. I saw that `SecurityExpressionRoot` is used, but when checking `hasRole()`, it relies on authorities to be set which is empty.

So I would love to have the `#oauth.clientHasRole()` functionality work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following this [spring document](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web-beans) and made my own security expression by generating a bean and referencing it. I don't like this as an answer and would like the `#oauth2` expressions to work out of the box. If anybody has the preferred answer, please post it.