# spring-security-oauth2 hasScope XML method security upgrade to what?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

As `spring-security-oauth2` obsoleted, see [EOL for Spring Security OAuth](https://spring.io/blog/2021/11/08/update-on-eol-for-spring-security-oauth),  I cannot use `#oauth2.hasScope([scope])` in XML config provided by [`OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.java`](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/main/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2SecurityExpressionMethods.java).

Expected to see AST parser or similar handler in either `spring-security-oauth2-jose`, `spring-security-oauth2-client`, `spring-security-oauth2-core` to accomplish that in the following example, [#oauth2 security expressions on method level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797721/oauth2-security-expressions-on-method-level).

Is there something I missed for XML config for OAuth2 scope checking?
Or I must implement it by `hasAuthority('SCOPE_[scope]')`?

Answer (score 0):

I have to switch to `hasAuthority("SCOPE_scope")`.

Spring Security converts scopes that follow the granted authority naming convention`, see [OAuth 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)